# How to display full content in timevis?

Tags: r, timeline

If a time window is relatively short and the content is long, `timevis` will only display a smart part. I can set the `end` to `NA` to show all the content, but I want to show the timeline too.

```
data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one"  , "Item two"  ,"Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c("2016-01-11","2016-01-12", "2016-02-04", NA))

#Item one and two are not fully displayed
timevis(data)
```

I am putting together a travel calendar for different members. If there are other better R packages for this need, please let me know.

Comment: After searching around for a while, I found `vistime` and think it's a better alternative for this task.